# Grouping elements in supergroups

Tags: php, arrays

At the moment I've got a set of arrays of elements, say,

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 4]
[5, 6, 7]
[1 , 44]
[5, 12]
etc...
```

What I want to do is to group these groups into supergroups if they share at least one element together. That is, the arrays above should become:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 44]
[5, 6, 7, 12]
```

The data I have is much larger and I wonder what is the efficient way of performing such operation.

My guess is take first array, go through all others, if there is intersection, join them and start from the top again, until there is no intersection of first with others. Then follow on to the second one etc...

Is there a better way to do it? I'm especially interested if it could be done easily in PHP, but pseudocode would be good as well..

Comment: what are the 'rules' for converting from one to the other?

Comment: I explained it in text - sharing at least one same element.

Comment: So if it was `[1, 12]` or `[2, 7]` array - you would get a single supergroup as a result?

Comment: Then output would be [1, 12] and [2, 7].

Comment: @sashkello: no, I mean if we add `[1, 12]` to the arrays in your question - would we get a huge single group instead then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is the best I came up with:

```
$j = 0;
while(array_key_exists($j, $groups)){
    $i = $j + 1;

    while(array_key_exists($i, $groups)){
        if(count(array_intersect($groups[$j], $groups[$i])) > 0){
            $groups[$j] = array_merge($groups[$j], $groups[$i]);
            $groups[$j] = array_unique($groups[$j]);
            unset($groups[$i]);
            $i = $j + 1;
            $groups = array_values($groups);
        }
        else{
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    }

    $j = $j + 1;
}
```